# Translating text with Google Cloud API in Python

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, jupyter-notebook, translation

I'm pretty new to coding so would appreciate your help on this. I'm trying to translate texts in Python with Google Cloud. I used the sample code from Google Cloud in my Jupyter notebook but it is not printing any translation. It isn't showing also any error. What I'm doing wrong?

```
text = 'Text you wish to translate'
target_language = 'fr'
project_id = '[xxx]'

def sample_translate_text(text, target_language, project_id):
    client = translate.TranslationServiceClient()
    contents = [text]
    parent = client.location_path(project_id, "global")

    response = client.translate_text(
        parent=parent,
        contents=contents,
        mime_type='text/plain',  
        source_language_code='en-US',
        target_language_code=target_language)
    for translation in response.translations:
        print(u"Translated text: {}".format(translation.translated_text))
```

Comment: Can you show us how you're calling `sample_translate_text`?

Comment: Not sure if I understood your question... I was actually trying to use another library to reach my goal, the goslate. But I'm still having problems. It retrieves an HTTPError 

import wikipedia as wiki
wiki.set_lang("pt")
corona_pt = wiki.page("Pandemia de COVID-19").content
print(corona_pt)


import goslate
gs = goslate.Goslate()
print(gs.translate(corona_pt,'en'))

Comment: I just saw now that goslate is no longer available... It worked when I first tried, but then showed the HTTPError. So, for the Google Cloud: I just used the sample code and inputed my project_id

Comment: I'm trying to translate a Wikipedia page from Portuguese to English: 


import wikipedia as wiki
wiki.set_lang("pt")
corona_pt = wiki.page("Pandemia de COVID-19").content
print(corona_pt)

Comment: You need to actually call the function after you've defined it: `sample_translate_text(text, target_language, project_id)`, are you doing that?

Comment: No. How should the code look like if I apply the function to this string conteined in **corona_pt**? `import wikipedia as wiki wiki.set_lang("pt") corona_pt = wiki.page("Pandemia de COVID-19").content print(corona_pt)`

Comment: What is the project ID in there , can anyone help me with this problem?, I have an API key but have no idea how to use GOOGLE CLOUD ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to actually call the function you've defined:

```py
def sample_translate_text(text, target_language, project_id):
    client = translate.TranslationServiceClient()
    contents = [text]
    parent = client.location_path(project_id, "global")

    response = client.translate_text(
        parent=parent,
        contents=contents,
        mime_type='text/plain',  
        source_language_code='en-US',
        target_language_code=target_language)
    for translation in response.translations:
        print(u"Translated text: {}".format(translation.translated_text))


import wikipedia as wiki
wiki.set_lang("pt")
text = wiki.page("Pandemia de COVID-19").content
target_language = 'fr'
project_id = '[xxx]'

sample_translate_text(text, target_language, project_id)
```

Comment: Okay. I got it! I just ran the code and it is showing the this message: InvalidArgument: 400 Text is too long. How could I fix that? The text is just a Wikipedia article...

Comment: You get this error as the Cloud Translation API is optimized for translating of short requests. The recommended maximum length for each request is 2K [code points](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_point). See the [Content Quotas](https://cloud.google.com/translate/quotas#content) page for more details. It is highly likely that the Wikipedia page is a lot larger than 2K code points.